# Matching part of a filename using the FilesMatch directive

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver

How do I match part of a filename using the FilesMatch directive?  For example, if I want to match "utilitiesForCurrentPage.js" or customWithOtherCharacters.css, how would I accomplish this?  I am currently using the directive(s) below.  Assume "utilitiesForCurrentPage.js" is contained in the files folder.

```
<Directory "/share/apache/files">
   ...
   ...
   <FilesMatch "^(custom*|utilities*)\.(css|gif|jpg|jpeg|js)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=1440, must-revalidate"
   </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `.` in your expression (`.` = match anything except newline):

```
# need dot here -----v   and ----v
<FilesMatch "^(custom.*|utilities.*)\.(css|gif|jpg|jpeg|js)$">
```

Comment: Why do you need to escape the 2nd dot but not the first one?